# Flux - components calling store directly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

Having spent some time working with flux (both ‘vanilla' and with various frameworks including alt and fluxible) I am left with a question about best practice with regard to loading the initial state of components. More specifically about components directly accessing the store to do it.

The flux ‘model’ prescribes a unidirectional flow of data from Action>Dispatcher>Store>View in a loop, yet it seems this convention is eschewed when loading the initial state of components, most docs/tutorials contain examples where rather than firing an action to get the data, the component calls a function on the store directly (examples below).

It seems to me that components should have little/no information about the store, only about the actions that they can fire, so introducing this link seems both unintuitive and potentially dangerous as it may encourage future developers to jump straight to the store from the component instead of going via the dispatcher. It also runs counter to the ‘Law of Demeter’ which Flux is supposed to adhere very strongly to.

What is best practice for this? Is there a reason that this always seems to be the case? Its quite possible that I have missed out something fundamental, so please let me know if so!

Thanks.

---

**Examples of components calling the store directly.**

Flux React example from the fb flux repo example chat app (https://github.com/facebook/flux/tree/master/examples/flux-chat)

**MessageSection.react.js**

```
getInitialState: function() {
    return getStateFromStores();
},


function getStateFromStores() {
    return {
        messages: MessageStore.getAllForCurrentThread(),
        thread: ThreadStore.getCurrent()
    };
}
```

Another example from the same repo for the TODOapp
(https://github.com/facebook/flux/tree/master/examples/flux-todomvc)

**TodoApp.react.js**

```
function getTodoState() {
    return {
        allTodos: TodoStore.getAll(),
        areAllComplete: TodoStore.areAllComplete()
    };
}
```

Example of the alt implementation of the above todo app: (https://github.com/goatslacker/alt/tree/master/examples/todomvc)

**TodoApp.js**

```
function getTodoState() {
    return {
        allTodos: TodoStore.getState().todos,
        areAllComplete: TodoStore.areAllComplete()
    };
}
```

and finally the alt specific tutorial:
(https://github.com/goatslacker/alt-tutorial/blob/master/src/components/Locations.jsx)

**Locations.js**

```
componentDidMount() {
    LocationStore.fetchLocations();
},
```

Comment: In the case of the `Locations.js` alt example, I think what was meant to be written was something like `LocationActions.fetchLocations()`. So instead of calling the method directly on the store, you would fire an action that would trigger the method on the store.

Comment: I suspect that is the case! However its such a common sight now (going direct to the store) that I wonder if i missed something in the theory!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the structure of you app looks like. Often you want to fetch some data before showing something to the user. What I have found to be a good practice is to have a high end component which fires on mount an action which fetches any initial data from an API. This means that when this action is done fetching it calls the store which caches the data and then emits a change. 
This change emit then sets in motion the re-rendering of the whole application.

This way you keep the uni-directional data flow. The whole point with Flux is letting the user extract the data flow functionality out of components to keep them more clean, discourage components to directly communicate with each other and decrease the amount of unnecessary properties which has to be passed around the application.

In the examples the initial state fetches some initial value from the store. This is a common way to fetch the initial value, but you could set it in the component as well. Both ways I would say is a good practice. This does not mean that every component is free to fetch whatever they like from the store.

Anyway, the goal would be to keep the code and data flow as intuitive as possible with Flux. All of this are reasons why there are so many implementations of Flux.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.

So that makes sense, I understand the need to run to the store for initial state, however I don't understand why the components in these examples are running DIRECTLY to the store, rather than firing an action (as suggested by Jonathan Huang). 

If we fire an action then the reference to the store in the component could be removed, which appears to make more sense.

Comment: As your application gets bigger you might want to emit changes to a "smaller" sub-tree of components. Thats why I think they added a direct store fetcher in one of the examples. If the application is small then its only confusing to fetch more than one place.